# Using locale translations for section settings in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working with Shopify sections and I'm trying to implement locale languages based on their documentation. The example provided in the docs is:

```
"locales": {
    "en": {
        "title": "Slideshow"
    },
    "fr": {
        "title": "Diaporama"
    }
}
```

Using this structure, I can output the localized title in the same section with: `{{ 'sections.slideshow.title' | t }}`. But, I'm facing a challenge when trying to utilize this in section's schema setting, for example:

```
{
    "type": "header",
    "content": "t:sections.slideshow.title"
}
```

It throws an error: *missing translation*. Even `{{ 'sections.eg-logo-carousel.direction' | t }}` just outputs the same string as-is.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `t:` you have  in:

```
"content": "t:sections.slideshow.title"
```

Actually references to a Locale file, not to the locales config of the section schema.

In a nutshell. Using `t:` on your schema configs refers to a locale File; Schema Locales can only be used to render on the template/html part, not to localize the Shopify editor section.

If you still wanna use `t:` create a section on you locales files like: `en.schema.json`

```
"sections": {
  "slideshow": {
    "title": "Slideshow"
  }
}
```

And then on the `fr.schema.json`

```
"sections": {
  "slideshow": {
    "title": "Diaporama"
  }
}
```

Finally you can edit you section schema to use:
`"content": "t:sections.slideshow.title"`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I understand the issue now. I'm developing custom widgets that I intend to distribute to many users. Given that each user might have distinct schema settings and themes, crafting a unique language schema file for each doesn't seem feasible. Is there no way to tap into the local schema's language directly?

Comment: Unfortunately no, even in the Dawn theme from shopify they use the locales files. https://github.com/Shopify/dawn